# A-Frame: rotate entity on mouse down using laser-controls

Tags: aframe

I have a component which is set on the entity which should be rotated on a mousedown event:

```
AFRAME.registerComponent('spin', {

init: function () {

    var self = this;
    this.mouse_down = false;
    // assuming only one controller for now
    this.laser = document.querySelectorAll('.laser-controls')[0];

    this.el.addEventListener('mousedown', function (e) {
        self.mouse_down = true;       
    });

    this.el.addEventListener('mouseup', function (e) {
        self.mouse_down = false;
    });
},

tick: function() {

    if (this.mouse_down) {

        var el = this.el;
        var rotationTmp = this.rotationTmp = this.rotationTmp || {x: 0, y: 0, z: 0};
        var rotation = el.getAttribute('rotation');
        rotationTmp.y = (this.laser.object3D.getWorldRotation()._y / (Math.PI / 180));
        el.setAttribute('rotation', rotationTmp);
    }
}

});
```

But it is not rotating properly (tested in Gear VR). What I would like is: hold any controller button and rotate the entity, until controller button is released. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that laser-controls events are properly fired and captured (no context provided). Modify the object3D directly:

`el.object3D.rotation.y = this.laser.object3D.rotation.y;`

The question needs additional information on what `not rotating properly` means. Notice that if you rely on the controller rotation the entity will stop being intersected and `mouseup` will fire prematurely.

Probably better to rely on button release that doesn't depend on the raycaster:

```
// Enables rotation when entity is clicked on
this.el.addEventListener('mousedown', function (e) {
  self.rotate = true;       
});

// Releases entity
this.laser.addEventListener('triggerup', function (e) {
  self.rotate = false;
});
```

Also notice you have two `laser-controls` entities in your scene (for left and right hand). GearVR has a single controller and only one of the entities will be actively tracked. The one that correspond to the configured handedness.

Try to do `this.laser = document.querySelectorAll('.laser-controls')[1]` to access the right hand one. Likely the one configured in GearVR

With `this.laser = document.querySelectorAll('.laser-controls')[0]` you are accessing the left hand controller. That's why you don't see any rotation.

A more general solution would be to check if the entity has an associated controller:

```
var hasActiveController = document.querySelectorAll('.laser-controls')[0].components['tracked-controls'];
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer and I tried your code. The issue is the same. If I click using the controller, the scene freezes. There must be something wrong with the code in the tick() function.

Comment: Any errors in console? Can you share a simple example on glitch to reproduce?

Comment: There are no errors in the console. The scene is not freezing anymore (was my fault, laser-controls did not exist before using them in the tick function), but I cannot spin the "blog post" around me in VR. This is the glitch: https://rough-asp.glitch.me/  Thanks!

Comment: The problem is that the laser-controls don't seem to have the rotation of the controller in my hand. But I saw that tracked-controls have the rotation info, which is set by the gearvr-controller. How to access the component from laser-controls, since the debug component does not show the tracked-controls in the DOM.

Comment: Updated and expanded answer. Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks! My issue was `this.laser = document.querySelectorAll('.laser-controls')[1]`.